# RewriteCond for string in ANY part of URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I am trying to write a rule that says the URL must not contain the text "sitemap" in ANY PART of the REQUEST_URI variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|Chrome-Lighthouse|google-structured-data-testing-tool|semrushbot|applebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|ahrefsbot|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff|\.svg))
   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sitemap
RewriteRule ^(index\.html|index\.php)?(.*) https://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  If the url is `https://new.mysite.com/sitemap`

it is still rewriting the URL even though it should have matched sitemap.  It also needs to ignore the rule for urls like: `https://new.mysite.com/sitemap/users/1` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace `REQUEST_URI` with `THE_REQUEST` variable as `REQUEST_URI` may change with other rules such as front controller that forwards all URIs to a  `index.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|Chrome-Lighthouse|google-structured-data-testing-tool|semrushbot|applebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|ahrefsbot|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpe?g|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpe?g|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/sitemap[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.html|index\.php)?(.*) https://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,L]
```